# how to control speed of carousel?

Tags: javascript, boot-strap, custom-properties, developer

Currently using bootstrap.min.js in my share point slider web-part.

i have custom property "Speed" ,trying to control speed of carousel from code behind

how to do it?

Comment: Please update your question with what you have done so far, Your question doesn't fit here properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some R&D ,find solution [for solution click here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

> Data Attributes Method
>   Add `data-interval="3000"`
>    to your carousel div like this.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap carousel, then you need to provide the data-interval attribute on your main carousel div to change the speed of carousel.
Ex.

```
<div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel"></div>
```

Here the value 3000 is in msec.

If you are not using bootstrap carousel, then specify more details what exactly you have done so far.

Comment: have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the ‘data-interval’ on the first line of code,

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000"></div>
```

1000 is 1 second, and 3000 is 3 seconds. You can replace ‘3000’ with your desired slider speed.

Below is the css you can change the speed:

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out !important;
-o-transition: -o-transform 1.2s ease-in-out !important;
transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

To see the full instruction, take a look at
[this post here](https://blog.identitydesign.us/bootstrap-carousel-slider-transition-speed-time-interval/).